# Simple carousel which updates its navigation buttons with the number of content items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I am trying to make a carousel which updates the navigation buttons according to list items in the `content` element.

```
<div id="content" class="content">
        <div>Something goes here</div>
        <div>Something goes here</div>
        <div>Something goes here</div>
        <div>Something goes here</div>
    </div>
```

And the navigation buttons updates itself.

```
<ul id="page_number" class="page_number">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Problem is that these nav items should not be static as here, these should be updated by creating in DOM as content item updates.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I had tried this. http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/light/

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you've tried but what I would do is

count the number of children div's found in #content:

```
var divcount = 0;

divcount = $("#content div").length;
});
```

then once you have defined the number of divs you can just use that number (divcount) to create the individual "nav items" (links) for pagination:

```
$("#content div").each(function( i ) {
  $("#content").append("<li>" + i + "</li>");
});
```

it could be simplified, Im sure, but you get the basic idea.  hope this helps.

example: [working demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/xJsak/)

Comment: Please give a fiddle link if possible.

Comment: @Akshaya Raghuvanshi - link added, let me know if it helps

Comment: That counting seems a long-winded way when `divCount = $("#content div").length'

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - you're right.   I've  updated to use .length, but originally wanted OP to see clearly that we were iterating  through the children divs -- .length works fine and probably has performance benefits as well as being shorter.  thanks.

Comment: @tamak Yeah, it seems to be working as updated as log as we add items in the #content element. But would it be possible to slide content items after clicking on these appended list items.

Comment: @tamak - Do you have any idea for this also?

Comment: @AkshayaRaghuvanshi - sure, I mean it just depends on how you want to do it -- theres a LOT of 'content slider' tutorials on the web so you could just follow one of those for how to handle the 'slide' of the clicked element.   I've updated the fiddle to show how to get the clicked item, so that helps a bit I suppose...
but basically you just setup the items with some type of x axis offset (using a class definition) so they are NOT visible, then when clicked, animate the x position so its visible.  if that makes sense... at least thats how I would approach it.